# python single linked list does not work properly

Tags: python, data-structures

the add method() only prints just two value, I want to print all the number what I added. size  does work well but I do not know why  value  does not work  when i want to print all  the value

`enter code here`

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value):

        self.next =None
        self.val =value
class single_linked_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head =None
        self.size =0


    def add(self,val):
        node =Node(val)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head =node
            self.size +=1
        else:
            self.head.next =node
            self.size +=1

    def __str__(self):
        vals =[]
        node =self.head
        while node is not None:
            vals.append(node.val)

            node =node.next
        return f"[{','.join(str(val)for val in vals)}]"

sl=single_linked_list()
sl.add(3)

sl.add(5)
sl.add(50)
sl.add(9)



print(sl)
print(sl.size)

# it just show these value :[3,9]
#4 as size fine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

The problem is that you are covering only 2 cases in the `add()` method:

1. There are **ZERO** nodes in the list.
2. There is only **ONE** node in the list

#### What about the case when there is more than 1 node in the list?

Let's assume there are two nodes in the list: `1 -> 2`

Now, to add `3` in the list, the `add()` method will check if the `head` is `None`. Which is not the case because there are 2 elements.

Then, it will simply add `3` as the `next` of `head`. Which was actually set to `2` before. Therefore, `2` is lost and the new list is `1 -> 3`

## Solution

To solve this issue, you have to edit the `add()` function and check if there is more than 1 node in your list. It can be done like this:

```py
def add(self,val):
  node = Node(val)
  if self.head is None:
    self.head = node
    self.size += 1
  else:
    curr_node = self.head

    # Go to the last element of the list
    while curr_node.next:
      curr_node = curr_node.next

    # Add new element after the last element
    curr_node.next = node
    self.size += 1
```

Comment: @GolamRabbani glad to know! Don't forget to mark it as the right answer and upvote it so that other programmers with the same problem can find it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value):

        self.next =None
        self.val =value
class single_linked_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head =None
        self.size =0


    def add(self,val):
        node =Node(val)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head =node
            self.size +=1
        else:
            self.head.next =node
            self.size +=1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your add method is not really adding nodes to the list, it is just replacing the `head.next` value. So you have at most 2 nodes in  the list with new values just replacing the second position.

Here's the fixed code for add method:

```
def add(self,val):
  node =Node(val)
  if self.head is None:
    self.head =node
    self.size +=1
  else:
    currentNode = self.head
    while currentNode.next:
      currentNode = currentNode.next
    currentNode.next = node
    self.size += 1
```

Here's a Repl.it link, if you want to see the output - https://repl.it/repls/RewardingVengefulTask